# error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:test/test.dart'

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

Since the latest flutter update my tests are broken.
It looks like the Dart test framework isn't available anymore:

```
error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:test/test.dart'.
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you've upgraded to a recent master, you'll find that `flutter_test` has removed its dependency on `package:test`. The package hasn't been removed or renamed, but you will need to specifically add it to you `dev_dependencies` in your pubspec now:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.5.1
```

The `test_api` package is just used to unify the versioning and reduce the depencies of `flutter_test`. It didn't replace `package:test`. There are also no breaking changes in any of these newer test versions.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I have deleted my wrong answer.

Comment: I have a direct dependency on test and am not using Flutter, but recently have started receiving this error in VSCode.

Comment: Huh. Seems that this time, VSCode had gotten into a bad state and reloading it solved the issue. Not sure about the other times it happened though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem  for me targeted URI doesn't exist was due to lib folder inside test package was not available at
file:///E:/APPS/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dartz-0.9.2/lib/
so I downloaded it from GitHub and add it there manually and restarted the IDE. And It worked.