# error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

A new error has recently appeared in Android Studio for **widget_test.dart**:

[image]

I am using the most up-to-date flutter version. '**flutter upgrade**' provides the following info:

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.0.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 676cefaaff (5 days ago) • 2022-06-22 11:34:49 -0700
Engine • revision ffe7b86a1e
Tools • Dart 2.17.5 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

I tried 'flutter pub get', 'flutter upgrade', restarting Android Studio, rebooting PC.
I tried adding "test:" into dev dependencies in pubspec.yaml as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208676/error-target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-packagetest-test-dart) question-answer.
Nothing fixed the issue. It continues to persist.
However, I can run my app and see it workable in emulator.

Any ideas how to fix this anoying error?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. As almost always, human factor.. :)

1. I checked that I do have this library in the directory where Flutter
   is installed. -> So logically that the linkage is broken.
2. I created a new Flutter project. -> there was no such error.
3. I searched in the 'new project' directory for "flutter_test" -> Such query was found in Dart_Packages.xml file. (obviously, I was not able to find "flutter_test" in my main project directory)
4. I understood that I need to add manually URI to flutter_test package, as it seems something is broken.
5. I opened ".packages" file in the project's root directory (don't ask why I opened it and not Dart_Packages.xml - I don't know :)) and added the following line:
   `flutter_test:file:///C:/Src/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/`

   then "flutter clean" and "flutter pub get" commands -> checked
   ".packages" file and my line dissappeared from there. -> so it seems
   "pub get" command breaks something. As "pub get" depends on
   pubspec.yaml, I compared pubspec.yaml files of two projects -> and
   surprisingly found this:

```
dev_dependencie                             тs:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

with NO error highlighted!

Just in case you don't see it at first sight, as I did :), there shall not be so many spaces and cyrillic letter "т" in 'dependencies' word. :)

**Long story short: check whether everything is fine with appropriate part of pubspec.yaml. :)**

Comment: I don't understand, what is this Yaml snippet means?
Are we supposed to paste like that`dev_dependencie                             тs:` ? Or you didn't have time to edit and fix that snippet?